# Can I force the hard coded option of a select with ng-Options to be the first?

Tags: angularjs

It seems that when a list (array of objects) for a `<select>` with ng-Options is loaded with some delay (when the list is loaded from an API, but also when i use a static list with $timeout) this list is added *after* the hard coded option and therefore the hard coded option becomes the last in the list.

This is the directive template:

```
<select ng-model="listId" ng-options="l.id as l.descr for l in List">
    <option value="" ng-if="textWhenNull">{{textWhenNull}}</option>
</select>
```

This is the directive:

```
.directive('showMyList', ['myStorage','$timeout', function (myStorage, $timeout) {
      return {
         restrict: 'CE',
         template: $('#myListTemplate').html(),
         scope: {
            listId: '=',
            textWhenNull: '@'
         },
         link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) => {
            // commented out the API call:
            //myStorage.readList().then(function (data) {
            //   $scope.List = data;
            //});
            $timeout(function () {
               $scope.List = [
                  { 'descr': 'option 1', 'id': 1 },
                  { 'descr': 'option 2', 'id': 2 },
                  { 'descr': 'option 3', 'id': 3 },
               ];
            }, 40);
         }
      };
   }])
```

And using it like this:

```
<div class="show-my-list" list-id="formData.listId" text-when-null="(nothing filled in)">
</div>
```

The result:

```
option 1
option 2
option 3
(nothing filled in)
```

What I want:

```
(nothing filled in)
option 1
option 2
option 3
```

**Note**
Because the list from the API already has the right order, I'd rather *not* use orderby! Unless -off course- if this is the only solution.

Don't know if this should be considered a bug, but it's definitely counter intuitive (to me).

**Update**
@ZackPatterson suggests this could be caused by the ng-if.

The docs say:

> If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

But when I make the timeout 4000 milliseconds I can clearly see the hard coded option is already there. Then the list is added, but the list-options are added *before* the hard coded option. So that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Not sure why it's doing them in that order, it should definitely be at the top... I have my `selects` done just like that calling an API. Hmmm

Comment: have you tried $scope.listId = '(nothing filled in)' in your controller to init your ng-model with the desired value at the top?, more info in the ng-options angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: @Jax700303 my interpretation of the docs is that the hard coded option is there especially to deal with ngModel not having a value. I understand what you are saying but it is not the solution I am looking for..

Comment: I'm going to guess that what's happening is by the time the ng-if directive on your dummy option is evaluated, your API call/timed-out static list has already been resolved, which results in the dummy being added onto the end. If you feel the need to keep that ng-if directive, you could get rid of the ng-options directive in your select and instead supply your options using an ng-repeat.

Comment: @ZackPatterson: that would mean that the hard coded option is removed from the DOM until the ng-if evaluates to true when it is reinserted again. I thought it would just leave it there and remove it when ng-if evaluates to false... Checking the docs for ngIf: '... otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.'. So it seems you are right. I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted the issue by using an ng-hide (or ng-show) instead of the ng-if. It has the same behaviour of only showing the option when I don't have a selected value and consistently adds the option as the first one.